# Probability for Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, covariance, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Both have Bernoulli distribution, equal to one with probability $0.5$. What is the probability distribution of the product $X_1 X_2$? What is the covariance between $X_1$ and $X_1 X_2$?

I am a beginner at statistics and quite confused by these conceptions. Would you please offer some guidance? Thank you!

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing.

Comment: Maybe start by answering this. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ each take only values 0 and 1, then what are the possible values of $Y=X_1X_2?$ And in particular, when is $Y = 1?.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable $X_1X_2$ takes on just two values, 0 and 1, so it also has a Bernoulli distribution, and we need only find $P(X_1X_2=1)$.  Now, $X_1X_2=1$ exactly when $X_1=1$ and $X_2=1$, so
$$P(X_1X_2=1)=P(X_1=1 \cap X_2=1)=P(X_1=1)P(X_2=1)=0.5\times 0.5=0.25$$
so $X_1X_2$ is Bernoulli with mean 0.25.

For the covariance:
$$\mathrm{cov}[X_1X_2,X_1]= E[X_1X_2X_1]-E[X_1X_2]E[X_1]= E[X_1^2X_2]-0.25\times 0.5$$
Now because $X_1$ is either 1 or 0, $X^2_1=X_1$,so $E[X_1^2X_2]=E[X_1X_2]=0.25$, and
$$\mathrm{cov}[X_1X_2,X_1]= 0.25-0.25\times0.5=0.125$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I now get it!

Comment: @ZQQ Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it completely solved your question

Comment: Sure! Where can I confirm to accept it? I am totally a new user to cross validated.